# How to name different kinds of alerts?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I need to distinguish two types of alert, one triggered when a value is below threshold and the other triggered when a value is higher than it. Is there different names or phrases meaning these two kinds of alerts?

For example, I receive almost ten e-mails from my co-workers every day.
If someday I get nothing, it's probably because the server is down. I want to set an alert to remind myself, then how do I name it?
On the other hand, when I receive over 100 e-mails, maybe our company is under attack. I also want to receive alerts, then how do I name it to make difference with the previous one?

I tried to name the first situation "Minimum Alert" or "Lower-bound Alert"; however, on second thought, these names may mean it is not possible for the actual value to fall below the set threshold. How to name or phrase them to avoid misunderstanding?

Comment: This is an opinion -based issue, sorry.

Comment: You might like "shortfall alert" paired with "excess alert" or "low volume alert" paired with  "high volume alert".

Comment: This is a reasonable question about how to find appropriate language for a specific circumstance. It is hard to see how it could be answered by procedural reference to authoritative references or by quotation from other sources.

Answer (score 1):

Your alerts relate to various states of *activity*.

> Activity = natural or normal function
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/activity)

If you apply a normal adjective to *alert* it is likely to be understood to apply to the alert and not to the relevant activity. This means a noun-adjective related to activity may suit your purpose better.

Your first alert stems from *quiescence*, which is inactivity; your second comes from *over-activity*.

> Quiescence = the state of being temporarily quiet and not active
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/quiescence)

I therefore suggest the noun-adjective phrases *quiescence alert* and *over-activity alert*.